# Extract information from multiple .txt-files into "one file"

Tags: loops, extract

I would like to ask for your help concerning the following issue of mine. Foremost I would be glad if you could provide me with a hint, *how to tackle* the following problem, especially, *which kind of software* I could use.
I do not want to inflate the topics, but I am struggling to come to a beginning which software I should consider and I do not have anyone I could ask nearby.

The scenario is the following:
I have a folder with "SEC EDGAR filings", i.e., [.txt-documents](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/2110/0001193125-15-069181.txt) enumerated from 1 to n.
What I want to do is

- open the file,
- read information on some variables (e.g. company name,
  filing date, state of incorporation etc.) and
- create a data set in table form out of this,

for each of the n filings - i.e., I would need to go through a loop from 1 to n.

The result would look like this:
[would-like-to-end-up-with-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVrfU.png), where "serial number" refers to the number of the .txt-file the information stems from.

So, reading this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592128/parsing-txt-files-and-extracting-information-in-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071029/import-multiple-txt-files-into-r), "R" seems to be capable of dealing with this kind of issues.
What I am asking for is if, according to your assessment, utilizing R could potentially - if I do not prove to be too stupid to "get into" R - lead me to the desired result?

I would be glad, if you could provide your point of view concerning the aforementioned problem.

Yours sincerely,
Mario

Comment: R can definitely get you there, the first results in google on how to learn what you want is [this book](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=strings+parsing+in+R&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Mqq2WJLkC7Sn8wfikYu4Cw). If you do not have any programming background, I'd also suggest to get a look at python, which -in my totally biased opinion- is easier to "get into" and can do the exact same thing

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I am relieved to read that R "can definitely get [me] there" as I hope to be capable of using it for the "more common" quantitative analysis next to SAS and STATA.
Thus, "getting into this" might yield the highest benefit.